# on resizing one dialog in multiple opened jquery ui dialogs, it is reflecting all others also

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Opening multiple dialog boxes at a time in one page. After resizing any of the dialog box, that same change(width/height) is affecting to all other opened dilogs

What might be the problem??

Comment: maybe because your setting them on the same class

Comment: We can only hypothesize here. Please, add a minimal example or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Yes, it might be. Because I am using class selector. But in my case I have to go by class selector only. Is there any chances of doing it even though those are all of same class?

Comment: Code snippet:                                                                       div.dialog({
  --------------------------
  resizableClass : 'pelem'
           }                                                                                                                                       Will it be any reason?

Comment: Yes, finally its working after changing "resizableClass" property as different classes.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Thanks all